# Mathematical Logic: A structure for Zermelo Frankel Axioms

Tags: set-theory, logic, axioms

I have taken an interest in mathematical logic to understand to source of mathematics as we know it today. And in this regard I have the following two questions:

1. What would a logical structure/interpretation look like for the Zermelo-Frankel axioms?
2. How is it possible to define a logical structure if we don't know anything about functions or sets yet? To be clearer, objects like functions or sets follow from the Zermelo-Frankel axioms, but these objects are already used in the definitions of structures and interpretations before we even know that these objects exist.

Comment: How is it possible to write a dictionary, if we don't know anything about words yet?

Comment: See https://mathoverflow.net/q/297942/1946.

Comment: I think there are also other much older questions, in the very early days of MO, addressing this issue.

Comment: Here are some other related MO questions. [Do set-theorists use informal set theory as their meta-theory when talking about models of ZFC?](https://mathoverflow.net/q/248965) [The sets in mathematical logic](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/62818), [Circular, or missing, definition in set theory?](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/300753)

Comment: See also the post [What could be a model of ZFC?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1717893/in-relatively-simple-words-what-could-be-a-model-of-sf-zfc)